# How to make Android app requiring camera support to run on Samsung Galaxy Mini and similar devices?

Tags: java, android, google-play

I have found out that Android app that has requirement `android.permission.CAMERA` will not even show up in Android Market for device like Samsung Galaxy Mini.

I think it is because Samsung Galaxy Mini has only fixed-focus camera.

Has anyone created app with camera requirements and has successfully deployed it on Android Market where it is possible to install it on Samsung Galaxy Mini ?

I still think there must be way around to do it. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, more and more googling and I have came up with this line adding to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```

But it requires to use minSDK=7